# fail to create function interval to prevent other function run

Tags: javascript

hello i try to create the function to prevent the other function to run for  10 minutes  IF user close the content and refresh the page.

the other function is to show the content when we scroll with 2 argument 
first:  it  will run the function with first argument with no interval, if user click close and refresh. it will run the second argument that give interval

heres my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/8c1ng49a/1/

please  look this code

```
var popUp= document.getElementById("popup");
var closePopUp= document.getElementsByClassName('popup-close');
var halfScreen= document.body.offsetHeight/2;
var showOnce = true;
var delay;

function slideUp(){
    popUp.style.maxHeight="400px";
    popUp.style.padding="10px 20px";
    popUp.style.opacity="1";
    if(popUp.className==="closed"){
        popUp.className="";
    }
}
function slideDown(){
    popUp.style.maxHeight="0";
    popUp.style.padding="0 20px";
    popUp.style.opacity="0";
    // add class  closed for cache
    if(popUp.className===""){
        popUp.className="closed";
        localStorage.setItem('closed', 'true'); //store state in localStorage
    }
}

// start interval
function startDelay() {
      delay = setInterval(slideUp, 1000);
}
// clear interval
function clearDelay() {
  window.clearTimeout(delay);
}
// check if cache heve  class  close
window.onload = function() {
    var closed = localStorage.getItem('closed');
    if(closed === 'true'){
        popUp.className="closed";
    }
}
// show popup  when scroll 50%
window.onscroll = function scroll(ev) {
    // first time visited
    if ((window.innerHeight+window.scrollY) >= halfScreen && showOnce) {
       slideUp();
       showOnce = false; 
    }
    //same user mutilple time visited the site 
    else if((popUp.className==="closed" && window.innerHeight+window.scrollY) >= halfScreen && showOnce ){
       startDelay();
       showOnce = false; 
    }
};

// close button when click close
for(var i = 0; i<closePopUp.length; i++){
    closePopUp[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        slideDown();
    });
}
```

my interval  didnt work onthe second argument its fire when i refresh, i dont know why.
but if add `startDelay` on my first arguments its work. but i need  to place the interval  on my second argu

Comment: Please read [ask]. You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: sorry ill edit the question right now

Comment: As soon as a function is assigned to window.onscroll, it will be executed every time the user scrolls. startDelay and stopDelay is never called in you example. You need to add the delay within the onscroll handler.

Comment: I don't see any call to `startDelay` inside the `if`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to make delay use setTimeout function. 
[Here is documentation of this function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

setInterval Repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.